# How to sort and have if statement sql

Tags: sql

So I have this project to do and im really confused on what to do

1.Assume the following two columns to the worker table are created before the execution of your program (Your program does not have to create these 2 columns):

```
|LEADER_LN    | LEADER_FN   |
=============================
|varchar2(25) | varchar2(25)|
```

These columns represent a leader that will be assigned to each worker. Your program will insert data into these columns for each worker.

Every worker will now have a leader assigned to him. The 2 columns above represent the last name and the first name of the leader. Here is the criterion for selecting the leader for each worker:

Leaders are assigned based on age and lodging. Each worker is assigned the next oldest worker that is living at the same lodge. For instance, Dick Jones has Pat Lavay as a leader. Pat Lavay has John Pearson as a leader. John Pearson has Andrew Dye as a leader. Andrew Dye has George Oscar as a leader. George Oscar is the oldest and has no one as a leader (leader columns are set to NULL). If the worker has no age (like a work team), they are assigned the oldest worker as the leader. Parse out the last name and first name for each worker and insert into the appropriate columns. If a worker does not live in a lodge, they do not have a team leader. If only one worker lives in a lodge they also have no team leader.

How would I even do this??

so far Ive got

```
select 
LAG (p.name) over (order by p.lodging, p.age) Leader_ln, p.name
--lead (p.name) over( order by p.age, p.lodging) Leader_fn --
from worker p;
```

Comment: You are close.  Remember what `partition by` does in this case.

Comment: but I have to sort it so if the person is the oldest person in the lodge the leader is null and I cant figure that out. 

so there are multiple lodges and each has X amount of people living in it. So how do I get it to show the null. There will be multiple people with null value in the leader slot

I also have to break the name up so like Joe Smith has to be broken up to where in the leader spot only joe shows up in the leader_FN and smith in the leader_LN